# JavaScript: How to push to an array inside an object that was created inside an arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So how do I push to the CONSUPTION array? Using THIS is not working and ia have no clue on how to make the ORDER work.

```
const createMenu = (menu) => ({
        fetchMenu: () => menu,
        consumption: [1,2],
        order: (string) => {
          this.consumption.push(string);
        },
        pay: () => {
          let cont = 0
          const cardapio = { ...menu.food, ...menu.drink}
          for (let itens of this.consumption){
            cont += cardapio[itens];
          };
          return cont;
        },
      });
```

Comment: Either assign the object to a variable and use that variable inside the function (instead of `this`) or use a method definition  (`pay() { ... }`) instead of an arrow function (then `this` will work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `order` arrow function to a regular function, it's not a good idea to use it in an object.

The reason for that is because that In regular functions the `this` keyword represented the object that called the function.
Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own `this`. The value of `this` inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of `this` in the closest non-arrow parent function.

```js
const createMenu = (menu) => ({
        fetchMenu: function(){ return menu},
        consumption: [1,2],
        order: function(string)  {
          this.consumption.push(string);
        },
        pay: function() {
          let cont = 0
          const cardapio = { ...menu.food, ...menu.drink}
          for (let itens of this.consumption){
            cont += cardapio[itens];
          };
          return cont;
        },
      });
      
      const menu = createMenu();
      console.log(menu.consumption);
      menu.order(3);
      console.log(menu.consumption);
```

More about `this` in arrow function could be found [here](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc)

Comment: To add to this there's also a shortcut syntax, so rather than `order: function(string) { ... }` you can write it as `order(string) { ... }`; it also avoids the problem with `this` and arrow functions.